# Scanned Image/PDF to Searchable Image/PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, ocr

Can anyone suggest me how to convert a scanned image into a searchable image or a scanned pdf to a searchable pdf ?
I have been stuck in this situation since quite a while now.
i have tried pdfocr application in ubuntu but no success.

Answer (score 4):

Tesseract version 3.03 supports creation of searchable PDF from image. For PDF, you can use GhostScript to convert it to image before sending it to Tesseract.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

Comment: I thought Tesseract just gives you a String of the text OCR'd from the PDF/image. Will it take a scanned-image PDF and turn it into a searchable-text PDF? (without altering the format/text too much!) ?

Comment: As said, you'll need to convert PDF to image first; Tesseract does not read PDF natively.

Comment: How to write the data retrieved by image_to_pdf_or_hocr to a pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no right way of doing this on Ubuntu. All OCR engines output plain text and there is no way to add that text as a hidden layer on PDF over the image text.

Option 1: Use **gscan2pdf** which will make you a searchable PDF, but the OCRed text is placed in the top-left corner of the page, is invisible and much too small.

Option 2: Use [PDF X-Change Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) which has an option to OCR and works correctly by adding a text layer over the scanned image which is in concordance with it. You'll have to run it in **wine**, because it is a Windows application.

Comment: Thanks cornelius for the options. Is pdf x-change viewer software free to use for commercial purpose ?

Comment: @user2722127 yes: "The FREE PDF viewer download of the PDF-XChange Viewer may be used without limitation for Private, Commercial, Government and all uses, provided it is not -: incorporated or distributed for profit/commercial gain with other software or media distribution of any type - without first gaining permission."